# PHP __DIR__ or SCRIPT_ROOT confusion

Tags: php, html, url, web, reference

I'm working ona  site and It's becoming more complex with folder structure.  I'm sure this is a simple problem for most but I keep getting mixed results.

my folder structure is something like:

```
Root:
    assets
       css
       js
       images
    core
       init.php
    categories
       sub category
           file.php
    includes
        header.php
        footer.php
```

and so on.

the init file will be included at the top of every document, excluding the header and footer.

the header and footer are included in every page.

I'd like to achieve something where instead of writing `include '../../includes/footer.php'` or include `'../includes/footer.php'` I can just write `include '$root. /includes/footer.php'` and not need to worry about the links.

The same applies for my nav bar (which is located in the header) if i want to go to index and i'm in a sub folder then it tries to take me to `site/subFolder/index.php` which doesn't exist.  I'd like to use the same idea her and have the nav links as root. file location

Could someone please help?  It's killing me and I'm certain it's so simple I'm looking past the obvious.

I've outputted DIR and SERVER_ROOT

I can hash something together using 
    `$bla = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];//= c:/www
     $bla.= "/nameOfMyRootFolder";`

but wondering what the best way is as i keep seeing references to **DIR**

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is defined in the webserver config and generally doesn't change.

`__DIR__` is the directory that *the file it is used in* resides.

eg: in docroot/includes/header.php `__DIR__ == 'docroot/includes'` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == 'docroot'`

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: so to maintain the same result throughout I could define DOCUMENT_ROOT as $a for example and the include $a. /whereverThisFileIs ?

Comment: My problem in doing that is that I get this as the file locatin : c:/www/NameOfMySite/index.php and of course that can't be accessed.

Comment: PHP should be able to, it does magic in the background to make back/forward slashes interchangeable in filesystem paths so you don't have to worry about whether the code is running on Windows or *nix.

Comment: think you misunderstood :)  When i use Doc_rot it results in c:/web.  The problem is that the site is live, hosted at home and when I call a link it then tries to go to c:/.... which fails.  I replaced it with http://nameOfSite.com/ and that worked but then yielded strange results when in subfolders like it was going to nameOfSite/subfolder/www.nameOfSite.com/subfolder/filename